# Completion modes are too intrusive. Is there an abstract API to fine tune usage per mode?

Tags: completion

So I'm looking for coding technique / code organization to make completion system pluggable for particular my mode, choice shouldn't affect other modes or preferences.

At the moment I use `completing-read` and it benefits from `ivy`. But I don't want to enable `ivy` globally.

What way can I give user of mode to choose preferred completion system for particular mode? Replacing `completing-read` globally is a disaster (be below).

**RATIONALE** I use `ido` for file completion. It has `C-f` (`ido-magic-forward-char` - fallback to non-Ido `find-file`).

I enabled `ivy` + `counsel` and file completion becomes disastrous, like `C-x C-f` is still from `ido` but with fallback to `ivy` where `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`) is not bound - so I can't create new file if some parts of it in existing file names...

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Is it that you want to use Ivy for all completion except file-name completion? If so, say so. If not, reread your question and try to make it more clear. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Done......

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Would it make sense to have a variable (e.g. `defvar` or `defcustom`) whose value would be a completion function? Variable `completing-read-function` is available for `completing-read`, but if some completion library doesn't use that then maybe you could come up with a variable whose value possibilities would accommodate multiple completion systems, in addition to `completing-read`.

Comment: @Drew Seems that it is OK to expose configuration by referencing function as a symbol value of some package specific variable, like `my-pkg/completion-function`